# How to use core php session value in laravel framework?

Tags: laravel

There are 2 projects:

1. Built in core php.[main project]
2. Built in laravel.

We are integrating laravel with php. In core php folder I am placing a laravel folder. In main project I am linking to laravel project by click on a particular link.

1. During login to the main project [core php], we are setting emailid into session.
2. I want that emailid session value in to laravel folders. how do I access that core php session value from laravel project folder.

Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052140/how-to-access-the-globals-session-and-cookie-from-a-laravel-app.  Just do `session_start(); echo $_SESSION['whatever'];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the globals $\_SESSION and $\_COOKIE from a laravel app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052140/how-to-access-the-globals-session-and-cookie-from-a-laravel-app)

Answer (score 0):

[Example link click here](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/)

but still there is some issues in that as laravel not able to access session object data