# PHP sessions not available in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

New to Laravel and having some problems with Sessions.

In my Linux server I have some PHP scripts stored on sub-domains, one of them is with Laravel.

I set all of them like so:

```
session_name("examplecom_session");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```

I can retrieve all my `$_SESSION` data array across all my sub-domains except in Laravel.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052140/how-to-access-the-globals-session-and-cookie-from-a-laravel-app

Comment: @ub3rst4r Yes, thanks...however seems irresolvable

Answer (score 1):

Doing `session('variableA, 'myvalue')` will actually set `myvalue` as the default value, this is not the correct way to set the value of a session variable.

Instead you would do `session(['variableA' => 'myvalue'])` to set the session using the global helper.

Most settings are done in the config files regarding your question about `session_set_cookie_params`.

I would recommend you to read up on it at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#storing-data

Comment: but I don't set the main session in a Laravel environment. Basically in Laravel I need to retrieve my session name (created on a different not Laravel main domain)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your session variables with Laravel session() function.
like

```
$a = session('VariableA')
```

it will return session $variableA 
or if you want to set $variableA as a session variable you just do: `session('variableA', 'value')`

Comment: Hi Radu, so I can use it like `$a = session('examplecom_session')`  ?

Comment: but then how do I `session_set_cookie_params` ?

Comment: All info about session you can find here:
[Laravel session] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#using-the-session)

Comment: don't focus on my question...I need to retrieve $SESSION data from a PHP domain

Comment: Then in the controller function you can use a Request $request  parameter
and after that:
$data = $request->session()->all();
It will give you back all the session data.